# Fetch Authorisation Header React Native

Tags: react-native

If I'm sending authorization header from postman it is working but not through code.

PostMan:

Headers:

```
Key: Authorization
Value: Basic
```

Authorization:

```
Username: test
Password: test
```

PostMan Result:

```
Successful Response
```

React Native Code:

Result:

> error: Please provide login credentials for the api.

```
     fetch(URL, {
          method: 'POST',
          Headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic', 
            Authorization:{
              'Username':'test',
              'Password':'test',
            },
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
          })
        })
    .then((response) =>  response.json())
    .then((responsenew) =>  
    {
});
```